# How to block a range of ip adresses with libirt's nwfilter for a specific mac(VM)

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, firewall, libvirt

I'm a bit lost how to block a range of Ip adresses(preferbly for a specific mac adress of a VM)

```
<filter name='local-fileserver-only' chain='ipv4' priority='-700'>
<uuid>blank for now</uuid>
<rule action='drop' direction='inout' priority='500'>
 <mac srcmacaddr='52:54:00:c9:88:0b'/>
<ip start='192.168.1.0' end'192.168.1.255/>
</rule>
<rule action='drop' direction='inout' priority='500'>
 <mac dstmacaddr='52:54:00:c9:88:0b'/>
<ip start='192.168.1.0' end'192.168.1.255/>
</rule>
</filter>
```

I'm starting to wonder if it is possible with nwfilter

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html#ipv4), there are no `start or` end` attributes supports for IPv4 rules. Your options are:

```
srcmacaddr
srcmacmask
dstmacaddr
dstmacmask
srcipaddr
srcipmask
dstipaddr
dstipmask
protocol
srcportstart
srcportend
dstportstart
dstportend
dscp
comment
```

If you want to black traffic to/from `192.168.1.0` through `192.168.1.255`, that corresponds to the network `192.168.1.0/24`. A 24-bit netmask means a mask of `255.255.255.0`. That gives us:

```
<filter name="block-192-168-1-0" chain="ipv4">
  <rule action="drop" direction="in" >
    <ip srcipaddr="192.168.1.0" srcipmask="255.255.255.0"/>
  </rule>
  <rule action="drop" direction="out" >
    <ip dstipaddr="192.168.1.0" dstipmask="255.255.255.0"/>
  </rule>
</filter>
```

If I apply this to a running vm using `virt-xml`:

```
virt-xml --edit --update --network filterref.filter=block-192-168-1-0 my-test-vm
```

That vm is no longer able to access hosts on the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Comment: Thank you this is what i'm looking for i was not familiar with network masking/subnettng. i was able to adept your answer to my needs after some research